# Proportion data with dependency using binomial generalized linear model

Tags: generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, proportion

I did an experiment on small tree branches with closed buds were a box containing 30 branches was monitored 3 times per week for the presence of leaves. The number of branches that have reached a developemnt stage was written down and when all branches had leaves the experiment was stoped.

my data is as below:

response variable: percentage of branches that reaches the leaf stage
explanatory variables:

forcing sums: continuous variable

cohort: categorical with two letter A and B denoting the amount of cold received before collection.

I tried using binomial glm with total success and failure at each monitoring date, however the assumption f binomial glm is that there should be no dependencies. I have dependencies since the monitored branches are the same always. What model can I use which can account for dependency.

Thank you